# Cannot align radio buttons and text no matter what I try

Tags: html, css

```
<?php
$array = array();
$array[1] = '1 Day';
$array[2] = '2 Days';
$array[3] = '3 Days';
$array[4] = '4 Days';
$array[5] = '5 Days';
$array[6] = '6 Days';
$array[7] = '7 Days';
foreach($array as $key=> $arr)
{
    if($key == 7)
    {
        echo '<input type=radio checked=true name=expires value=$key>$arr';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<input type=radio name=expires value=$key>$arr';  
    }
} 
?>
```

In the code above the radio buttons are about 7 pixels below the level of the text, and I would like them aligned with the text. No matter what I have tried, I cannot seem to get the radio buttons aligned with the text. I can get the radio buttons "raised" up, but then the labels never appear, just arr. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: PHP wont help here mate...please paste your rendered html and css...

Answer (score 0):

Write in your css

```
input[type="radio"] {
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array();
$array[1] = '1 Day';
$array[2] = '2 Days';
$array[3] = '3 Days';
$array[4] = '4 Days';
$array[5] = '5 Days';
$array[6] = '6 Days';
$array[7] = '7 Days';
foreach($array as $key=> $arr)
{
if($key == 7)
{
echo "<input type=radio checked=true name=expires style='position: relative;bottom: -2px;' value=$key>$arr";
}
else
{
echo "<input type=radio name=expires style='position: relative;bottom: -2px;' value=$key>$arr";  
}
} 
?>
```